# Backing Up VMs and Host Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, windows-server-2012

I am just starting to learn about virtual machines and all of the great features they bring. I have recently been thinking of how one would go about backing up a VM environment. Theoretically, if I had a server environment with 1 host server (2012 R2) with two virtual machines on it running 2012 R2 as well, what would be the best practice for backing them up? Is there specialized software for this? Would I need to run 3 separate backups, etc..

An explanation to this would be more than appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any solutions that are meant to run on the host and backup virtual machines. Someone else may know of a solution that does that.

There are serious technical challenges to backing up what is essentially just one big VHD file and will make recovery very difficult and time consuming, if you needed something like a single file restored in the guest. There are other potential issues to consider, like volume shadow copies especially if you are running any databases.

I would strongly advise that you run the backup agents on the virtual machines and backup each just like they are a full stand alone system. This will allow you to recover one or the other in all the various ways you would expect. There isn't really any reason to backup the host. This is usually reserved as just the hypervisor and can be reinstalled pretty quick. If you do choose to backup the host also, you should make sure your VMs are stored on a different partition and you are not letting the backup software touch them.

Keep in mind this is simply for backup. If you are trying to achieve high-availability Server 2012 R2 has a few options available.

Comment: So would the built in windows server backup solution work for each vm? In theory have two external drives to backup each vm. If the host machine crashes, how would you restore the two vms?

Comment: If Windows server backup is suitable for your needs, then yes. I prefer a more robust backup solution. Best practice says you won't have your VM files stored on the same drives as your host operating system. This is for both performance and backup purposes. So, the host machine "crashing" will not affect the VMs. You simply restore or reinstall the host operating system and the secondary drive with the VMs is still there. It's a simple matter to re-add them to the Hyper-V management console.

Comment: What solution do you suggest?

Possibly I do not fully understand this backup procedure, but if the host machine is not being backed up, and one of the drives housing a vm fails, how is the vm put back into Hyper V? Just from a bare metal backup of the vm?

Comment: There are a lot of backup solutions available and it depends on your budget, your rpo/rto, and other needs of you or your organization. I say respectfully, coming up with a disaster recovery plan is not something to take likely, there is alot of information and vendors available for that, and not something I can take on in a few hundred characters. Your second question - Yes, you restore the VM just like you would if it was a physical machine. You would recreate the VM, then boot the VM with a recovery disc/iso/usb drive and run the restore.